# How to change the icons to default to xls format?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, icons, windows-server-2003

I have installed both Microsoft office 2007 & Open office 3.2 on my windows 2003 server.
The icons when I check shows up in the open office format even though it opens up using Microsoft office 2007.

I want to change the format that the icons appears on my user profile to Microsoft office. When  checked it here in the Tools section it says Microsoft Office Excel [Tools > Folder options > File Types > XLS.]

But the ions still appear in open office format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were already almost in the right place. Open Tools > Folder options > File Types, click on XLS file type.

- Now click on the Advanced button at the bottom of the window.
- A new window opens, click Change Icon...
- Click Browse and navigate to Excel.exe (in my case C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE) and choose an icon to your liking

Repeat for any other file types you might like to change.

[image: screenshot]